# CSS and different size of monitor?

Tags: css, image, background-image

I am doing a website (WIP). I encountered some CSS problems, hope you guys can help me.

My current situation:

- I have am image, lets called it "bg.png" with the width about 2500px, and at the center of the background image has my logo.
- My website should target all size (from small 800 x 600 to 2400 x XXX) users.

My problems:

- How do I centralize the background image(bg.png), so that the logo always positioned in the centered(horizontally) of different size of monitors screen?

Comment: As you're a new user, make sure to click the "accept" tick if an answer meets your needs.

Comment: Question well stated by the way (current situation -> problem/desired behaviour).

Comment: You should know that some screens are larger than 2500. And that you can expand something on multiple screens too.
So 2500 is not a big enough limit.

Comment: Thanks guys, you all are so friendly and helpful :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
body { background: url('bg.png') 50% 50% no-repeat; }
```

This will place the image at full-size at the center of the page, and the user will see as much of this background image as their browser window permits.

Comment: thanks, it works. But I need to wait another 9 minutes to accept an answer. Thanks Graphain

Comment: Welcome studdler, glad to help out. It is worth registering so you can keep track of your questions and answers over time and to encourage others to help you out.

Comment: Hi Graphain, it works on FF, chrome, opera and safari. But it doesn't work on IE, the image does not show up.

Comment: Problem solved. instead of putting all the properties in 1 line like this: background: url('images/bg.png') 50% 50% no-repeat; I seperate them into this: background: url('images/bg.png') no-repeat; background-position: 50% 50%;

Comment: Nice fix. Maybe the order matters on IE or perhaps one property is missing (like bg colour at start).

Answer (score 0):

If it was just a logo file you could use

```
<style>
img
{
    position:absolute;
    left:-50%;
    top:-50%;
    z-index:-1;
}
</style>
```

Comment: This doesn't exactly centre the image.  The left of the image is centred, but the centre of the image isn't centred.

Comment: To do that, add margin-left: -50%, margin-top: -50%.

Answer (score 0):

```
#your_img {
  width: 2500px; //In example 2500px
  margin: 50%;
  padding: -1250px; // 2500 divided by 2
}
```

It probably don't work on Internet Explorer, but you can use a little hack with position: absolute, as above

Answer (score 0):

```
#your_img {

   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   margin: -1250px;
}
```

This solution is necessary, when you put img element onto another box. But be careful - it might change size of parent's box.